# Main recursively called without local variables

Tags: c

What is output of the following:

```
int main() 
{
    printf ("welcome");    
    main ();    
    return;    
}
```

Options:

1. Main is called infinite times
2. main is called 65535 times.
3. main is called 32765 times.
4. Stack overflow.
5. Compilation error.

My analysis: I think Option 1. as correct. Option 2,3and 5 definetly not. i dont think for Option 4 also. Reason, I believe stack overflow could have happened, if main function used some local variables consuming memory. So, i think option 1 as correct one! I agree recursive function causes stack overflow, but that also depends on what the functions implements. In this case, only printf is printed. Please let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running the code to find out what happens?

Comment: if try in codepad.org, it runs infinetly until timeout happens. I didnt try in any hardware environment.

Comment: The stack frame is so small that it might not overflow before the timeout occurs.

Comment: Or, compile it and read the assembly output.  E.g. https://godbolt.org/z/q3fRG1.  With no optimizations you'll see a `call main` instruction, which implicitly pushes the current return address onto the stack.  So the stack does grow with every call and will eventually overflow.

Comment: `main`  should not be recursive

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch While it's generally a bad idea, I think C allows it (but C++ doesn't, and I don't know about other C dialects). But is anything about this question really specific to `main()`? The issue would be the same with any other function that has no parameters or local variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is implementation-dependent. The language doesn't say anything about how function calls are implemented, they just have to produce the correct results for valid programs.

In most implementations I'd expect #4. Even if you don't have local variables, it still needs a stack frame to hold the return location.

If your function were tail-recursive, and the compiler optimizes tail calls, then you would avoid stack overflow. For this to work, the function would have to end with:

```
return main();
```

Comment: but it doesn't reaches the return statement.

Comment: If the compiler could figure that out, it probably would have warned that `return` is unreachable. So it's probably compiling the function as if `main()` could return and it needs to save the state.

Comment: Actually this definition is TCE-able as-is: the compiler can see that the return value of the recursive call is unused and the syntactic return doesn't depend on it, so no stack needs to be maintained except the outermost level (which implicitly returns 0 simply because it's `main`). But TCE is fragile in C even in the compilers that claim to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for a moment that recursively calling `main` is not a good idea, you'll end up with a stack overflow if you run this code.

Even with no local variables, the stack still needs to keep track of the function's return address.  That return address will add up and eventually blow up the stack.

Comment: I just found a link which explains the same. https://www.programtopia.net/c-programming/docs/recursion-c-programming Is this wrong then?

Comment: @xyz101 In theory recursion can be infinite, but in practice machines use a stack which needs to store the function's return address, and eventually the stack will fill.

Comment: the function call doesnt have any parameter. so, then also will it be the same case? what state of the function will be stored in stack frame?

Comment: @xyz101 The return address of the calling function.  That's how it knows where to return to.

Comment: [gcc is smart enough to convert the recursion to an infinite loop at -O3.](https://godbolt.org/z/KF77vG)

Answer (score -1):

It will be first compilation error in you case as function of return type int is not returning any value.

There is also a case of stack overflow as every time the main() is called stack stores the address of return statement which is to be executed after main which in you case not happens and function again call itself.

Thus after every call stack will have address of return statement.